# How can I show a window with the a name given as parameter in Windows in C++

Tags: c++, windows, window

I would like to make my software usable for Linux and Windows (Linux already works). Now I still need some functions so I can run the software on Windows, too.

I am currently trying to use the `EnumWindows()` function to get the window names and then show the window in the foreground (which matches the parameter).

```cpp
static BOOL CALLBACK setWindowFocus(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);

    // List visible windows with a non-empty title
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && length != 0) {
        // Check if it is the right Windowshandle
        if ( windowTitle.compare(programname) == 0 ) <-- programname is a static variable
        {
            // Set application to the foreground
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Additionally, I used this to create the variable:

```cpp
std::string programname;
```

And this to call it:

```cpp
static void setWindowFocus(std::string programname)
{
    std::cout << "Setting focus to window." << std::endl;
    tempsavedProgramname=programname;
    EnumWindows(setWindowFocus, NULL);
}
```

That is working, as long as it is in `main()`. But, I would like to have it in an extra class with some other functions (I would like to remove the `static` variable too, if possible).

Is there a way I can use the `EnumWindows()` function with an anonymous function, or something?

Can I use something like this to pass a string to the function:

```cpp
EnumWindows(setWindowFocus, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(stringvariable));
```

Or, are there other ways which I can try to reach my goal?

Includes which I used for the code:

`Windows.h`
`winuser.h`
`string`
`iostream`

I hope that I did not forgot one.

Comment: You could use it in a class by setting the 2nd parameter to `this` and then casting it back in the callback.

Comment: Do you mean the LPARAM?Like this: ```EnumWindows(setWindowFocus, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));```

Comment: Does your process have foreground when you call this code?  `SetForegroundWindow` is highly restricted to prevent interrupting what the user is doing.

Comment: On a side note, your callback is leaking the allocated `buffer`, you need to `delete[]` it when you are doing using it. I would get rid of the `buffer` completely and just use `windowTitle` as the buffer for `GetWindowText()`, eg: `int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd); std::string windowTitle(length+1, '\0'); windowTitle.resize(GetWindowText(hWnd, &windowTitle[0]/*or: windowTitle.data() in c++17*/, length + 1));`

Comment: Hard to say since it is an automation software so there won´t be a user when the software is executed. I would like to invoce the software like it on linux with cronejobs or maybe autostart. As I tested the code I had other windows in the foreground too and it worked, but when I interpreded you answer right that is not  always is the case?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thanks, that code is corrently just put together from other Stackoverflow questions I found. So any help is aprechiated. (I did do mutch with windows so far so I have not mutch experince there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `LPARAM` to pass a `string` variable into your callback, eg:

```cpp
static BOOL CALLBACK setWindowFocus(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    std::string &programname = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(lparam);

    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);
    delete[] buffer; // <-- ADD THIS!

    /* I would use this instead:
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    std::string windowTitle(length+1, '\0');
    windowTitle.resize(GetWindowText(hWnd, &windowTitle[0], length + 1));
    */

    // List visible windows with a non-empty title
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && (length != 0)) {
        // Check if it is the right Windowshandle
        if (windowTitle == programname)
        {
            // Set application to the foreground
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

```cpp
static void setWindowFocus(std::string programname)
{
    std::cout << "Setting focus to window." << std::endl;
    EnumWindows(setWindowFocus, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&programname));
}
```

And yes, you can use a C++11 lambda for the callback, rather than a `static` class method, but *only* if you use a *non-capturing* lambda, which is implicitly convertible to a function pointer (*capturing* lambdas are not).  Fortunately, the `LPARAM` makes that a possibility, eg:

```cpp
static void setWindowFocus(std::string programname)
{
    std::cout << "Setting focus to window." << std::endl;
    EnumWindows(
        [](HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) -> BOOL {
            std::string &programname = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(lparam);
            // ...
        },
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&programname)
    );
}
```

Now, that being said, there is a much simpler solution - since you already know the exact window text you are looking for, you can use [`FindWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) instead of `EnumWindows()`, eg:

```cpp
static void setWindowFocus(std::string programname)
{
    std::cout << "Setting focus to window." << std::endl;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, programname.c_str());
    if (hWnd != NULL) {
        // Set application to the foreground
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was exaclty what i was searching for I wonder why google did not gave me that function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the callback wrapped up in a class

```
class enum_windows {
protected:
    virtual BOOL call_back(HWND hwnd)  {
        // Your code here
        return TRUE;
    }
public:
    void start() {
        EnumWindows([](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {
            enum_windows * obj = reinterpret_cast<enum_windows *>(lParam);
            return obj->call_back(hwnd);
        }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
    }
};
```

(You've already accepted an answer - I'm a slow typer ). I'll leave this here anyway.

Comment: Thank you too. It is still helpful for me but for something else :D